# Compiling zathura pdf plugin on mac ld error

Tags: c++, macos, pdf, linker, osx-yosemite

I am trying to install zathura-pdf-poppler-0.2.5 on a Mac OS X running Yosemite. When I try and make, I get the following error:

```
LD pdf.so
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_zathura_document_get_data", referenced from:
      _pdf_page_links_get in links.o
      _pdf_page_init in page.o
  "_zathura_document_get_password", referenced from:
      _pdf_document_open in document.o
  "_zathura_document_get_path", referenced from:
      _pdf_document_open in document.o
  "_zathura_document_information_entry_list_new", referenced from:
      _pdf_document_get_information in meta.o
  "_zathura_document_information_entry_new", referenced from:
      _pdf_document_get_information in meta.o
  "_zathura_document_set_data", referenced from:
      _pdf_document_open in document.o
      _pdf_document_free in document.o
  "_zathura_document_set_number_of_pages", referenced from:
      _pdf_document_open in document.o
  "_zathura_index_element_new", referenced from:
      _pdf_document_index_generate in index.o
      _build_index in index.o
  "_zathura_link_free", referenced from:
      _pdf_page_links_get in links.o
  "_zathura_link_new", referenced from:
      _poppler_link_to_zathura_link in utils.o
  "_zathura_page_get_document", referenced from:
      _pdf_page_links_get in links.o
      _pdf_page_init in page.o
  "_zathura_page_get_height", referenced from:
      _pdf_page_links_get in links.o
      _pdf_page_search_text in search.o
  "_zathura_page_get_index", referenced from:
      _pdf_page_init in page.o
  "_zathura_page_set_data", referenced from:
      _pdf_page_init in page.o
  "_zathura_page_set_height", referenced from:
      _pdf_page_init in page.o
  "_zathura_page_set_width", referenced from:
      _pdf_page_init in page.o
  "_zathura_plugin_add_mimetype", referenced from:
      _zathura_plugin_register in plugin.o
  "_zathura_plugin_set_name", referenced from:
      _zathura_plugin_register in plugin.o
  "_zathura_plugin_set_register_functions_function", referenced from:
      _zathura_plugin_register in plugin.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [pdf.so] Error 1
```

I have the following path set in $PKG_CONFIG_PATH:

```
/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig:/opt/X11/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/Cellar/zlib/1.2.8/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/Library/ENV/pkgconfig/10.10
```

Does anyone know how to fix the problem.

Many thanks

Comment: Do you mean `zathura-pdf-poppler`? If so, do you have dependencies installed, mainly: `zathura (>= 0.2.0)`?

Comment: yes, I have installed zathera 0.3.2 and now I am trying to install the plugin zathura-pdf-poppler(0.2.5) so that I can view pdf's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the exact reason that this happens, but I have applied a patch to makefiles and config.mk from MacPort. You can download them in plaintext and use `patch Makefile < make.diff` and `patch config.mk < config.diff` to apply the patch.

[patch files](https://trac.macports.org/browser/trunk/dports/office/zathura-plugin-pdf-poppler/files?rev=120312&order=name)

I had to change `/usr/lib/zathura/pdf.dylib` to `/usr/lib/zathura/pdf.so` after the `make install` in order to make zathura display pdf files.

Comment: Thanks Ray, I have now been able to run make successfully, but when I run sudo make install, I get an error saying that package `xcb-shm` was not found in the pkg-config search path. However, I have run `export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig:/opt/X11/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/Cellar/zlib/1.2.8/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/Library/ENV/pkgconfig/10.10` and `xcb-shm` in directory `/opt/X11/lib/pkgconfig` which is in the PKG_CONFIG_PATH. Any Ideas?

Comment: `sudo -E make install` -E  keeps your environments

Comment: Thanks Ray. That worked but when I run zathura to open a pdf with `zathura file.pdf``, I get the following error message: `Dynamic session lookup supported but failed: launchd did not provide a socket path, verify that org.freedesktop.dbus-session.plist is loaded!
error: Unknown file type: '(null)'`

Comment: I moved `org.freedesktop.dbus-session.plist` to `/Library/LaunchAgents/` and ran `launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchAgents/org.freedesktop.dbus-session.plist`. Now zathura file-pdf.pdf launches X11 with no errors but it doesn't show a window or the pdf.

Comment: Did you try change `/usr/lib/zathura/pdf.dylib` to `/usr/lib/zathura/pdf.so`

Comment: Yes, I have changed it and it hasn't made any difference.

Comment: I killed the launchd process org.freedesktop.dbus-session.plist and now I can view a pdf but now the error message comes back: `Dynamic session lookup supported but failed: launchd did not provide a socket path, verify that org.freedesktop.dbus-session.plist is loaded!
warning: Failed to loads bookmarks.`

Comment: Ray, after your help last time, I get zathura working but now when I try it today, x11 opens but a window does not display. I think the only change has been an os x update to 10.10.3. Do you have any idea how to fix it. Thanks Paul

Comment: Ray, I solved the problem. I had the org.freedesktop.dbus-session still loading in my launchctl daemon